# Error occured in react.production.min.js after deploying react app to the aws amplify

Tags: javascript, reactjs, amazon-web-services, aws-amplify

I've made complex react app but after deploying it on **aws amplify** i've got these errors, i don't know why i got these errors, on local it works perfectly
here is the error log

```
Error: Minified React error #321; visit https://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html?invariant=321 for the full message or use the non-minified dev environment for full errors and additional helpful warnings.
at j (react.production.min.js:18)
at t.useContext (react.production.min.js:22)
at oe (hooks.js:18)
at Lu (Body.js:18)
at li (react-dom.production.min.js:157)
at Gl (react-dom.production.min.js:267)
at Is (react-dom.production.min.js:250)
at Bs (react-dom.production.min.js:250)
at Ms (react-dom.production.min.js:250)
at bs (react-dom.production.min.js:243)
ul @ react-dom.production.min.js:216

Uncaught Error: Minified React error #321; visit 
https://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html? react-dom.production.min.js:260 
invariant=321 for the full message or use 
the non-minified dev environment for full errors and additional helpful warnings.
at j (react.production.min.js:18)
at t.useContext (react.production.min.js:22)
at oe (hooks.js:18)
at Lu (Body.js:18)
at li (react-dom.production.min.js:157)
at Gl (react-dom.production.min.js:267)
at Is (react-dom.production.min.js:250)
at Bs (react-dom.production.min.js:250)
at Ms (react-dom.production.min.js:250)
at bs (react-dom.production.min.js:243)
```

if you know any solution or way to solve these kind of errors please answer it here! thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

so here is the answer of this question!
in package.json, i moved react and react-dom to peerDependencies

```
"peerDependencies": {
"react": "^17.0.2",
"react-dom": "^17.0.2"
},
```

so try this, it should solved the problem ;)